# Creating a project using sass

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Somehow the style part is ignored creating a new project using angular-cli.

```
ng new sassy-project --style=sass
```

After this, creating a new component still creates `.css` files and no `scss`.

Changing it later again manually, using `ng set defaults.styleExt scss` doesn't change it either but throws an error complaining `styleExt is not a known property.` Even adding the property doesn't help.

Entire log:

```
$ ng set defaults.styleExt scss
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
styleExt is not a known property.
Error: styleExt is not a known property.
```

---

**Version**

```
$ ng -v
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
angular-cli: 0.0.39
node: 5.3.0
os: darwin x64
```

Comment: Using `ng new sassy-project --style=scss` does work for me. Components are generated with scss-style, too.

Comment: @j2L4e not for me... It does the same as described.

Comment: what's `ng -v` say?

Comment: You are about 20 versions behind. It appears styleExt was not even implemented by that time. But be careful, if you upgrade now, it will break your setup!

Comment: Well, this is what `npm install -g angular-cli` provides...

Comment: That's because of semantic versioning. It'll only install newer versions beginning with `0.x.x`. Use `npm purge -g angular-cli && npm i -g angular-cli`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123526/discussion-between-cocoseis-and-j2l4e).